# Populate dropdown in datagrid view based on a column value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to populate a drop down column in a `DataGridView` in a windows form based on a main activity Id column.

I have `main activity id` and other details in the `DataGridView` returned from a stored procedure. So when the user clicks the sub activity column, I need to populate the sub activities based on this parent id, then based on this sub activities I need to populate the other dropdown column.

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════╗
║ ActivityId   ║ ActivityName     ║ ParentId ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 10611801     ║ FootPath         ║ 106118   ║
║ 10611802     ║ Staggared Drains ║ 106118   ║
║ 10611901     ║ Manual Weeding   ║ 106119   ║
║ 10611902     ║ Chemical Weeding ║ 106119   ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════╝
```

I have tried to populate the column on `DataGridView.CellClick` event, but I am getting an

> invalid value exception

on different mainactivity.

```
public partial class CustomDropDown : Form
{
    public CustomDropDown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void BindGridData()
    {
        string selectQuery = "Select ActivityId as MainActivityId,ActivityName as MainActivity from ACTIVITY_MASTER_MST where ParentId is null";
        var mainDataSource = Common.GetDatas(selectQuery);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = mainDataSource;
        string sourceQuery = "Select convert(varchar,ActivityId) as SubActivityId,ActivityName as SubActivityName from ACTIVITY_MASTER_MST";
        var subActivityDataSource =Common.GetDatas(sourceQuery);
        PopulateGridDropDown(SubActivityId, subActivityDataSource, "SubActivityName", "SubActivityId");

    }
    public void PopulateGridDropDown(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbo, DataTable source, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        cbo.DataSource = source;
        cbo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        cbo.ValueMember = valueMember;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        var rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        string columnName = this.dataGridView1.Columns[index].Name;
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "SubActivityId":

                var parentId = dataGridView1[MainActivityId.Name, rowIndex].Value;
                var strQuery = "Select convert(varchar,ActivityId) as SubActivityId,ActivityName as SubActivityName from ACTIVITY_MASTER_MST where ParentId=" + Convert.ToInt32( parentId);
                DataTable source = new DataTable();
                source = Common.GetDatas(strQuery);
                PopulateGridDropDown(SubActivityId, source, "SubActivityName", "SubActivityId");
              break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void CustomDropDown_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGridData();
    }


}
```

Please share your ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It may help us to help you if you add the relevant code that throws the exception and the stack trace to your question.

Comment: All combo boxes in a column must have the same data source. A trick I have used in the past is to fill the data source with every value, then on `EditingControlShowing` event you apply a filtered data view so the user only sees the relevant selections.

Comment: I am getting the same error even after i moved the code to **EditingControlShowing** event,Please help.